# Simple ListActivity crashing

Tags: android, crash, listactivity

[edit] logcat here: https://app.box.com/s/08yuzv8hq4bgt7qpemy0

It's this really simple training app I'm doing and the app keeps crashing upon launch:

```
package com.example.myown;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.array.arraye);
      setListAdapter(adapter);

      ListView lv = getListView();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Can you see any reason this would happen? It crashes as soon as I open the app - the activity appears with no list view and then I get the usual "MyOwn has stopped".

This is the activity_mail.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >


  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">MyOwn</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string-array name="arraye">
    <item>one</item>
    <item>two</item>
    <item>three</item>
    <item>four</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: you are set layout in ListActiviy , so could you post your layout ?

Comment: and don't forget to post LOGCAT also error

Answer (score 2):

NOTE :

When creating a Listview with ListActivity then there are two things you must make note of ,the ListView with the android:id attribute should be set to @android:id/list ( NOT android:id="@+id/list" ).

if you defined ListView with the android:id attribute and set it to @+id/list then it will give an error.

```
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to load an array resource into the ArrayAdapter. The constructor that is calling is expecting the resource ID of a textview to place your strings in.

Instead you should load the array in from the resources and put that into the adapter, like so:

```
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arraye);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

Comment: Thanks! And now the long wait for the emulator to start!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here because you use `ListActivity` which has its `ListView` but you are using custom layout so the `Activity` will read the layout and try to find its `ListView` but  you don't include it in the layout ,  so you need to add its `ListView` like that :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here the `Activity` code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String [] array = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arraye);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(List_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
      setListAdapter(adapter);
      ListView lv = getListView();
}
```

and i put array string in resources :

```
 <string-array name="arraye">
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item1</item>
</string-array>
```

feed me back

Comment: Still crashes, unfortunately. I'm uploading the logcat file and posting it now.

Comment: the error said the activity doesn't exists , be sure that the activity is defined in mainfest.xml

Comment: take look on edited answer i tested it and work with me now , feed me back

Comment: Thank you! I really have to go to bed now (it's really late here) but I'll give you feedback tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: This is really strange: that's exactly how my code looks (well, with the exception of you calling it List_Activity and me calling it MainActivity at the adapter arguments) and it still crashes on the emulator.

Comment: look try to make array in your code instead of resource file , and feed me back

Comment: It worked! That solved it but I can't understand _why_ it solved the problem!

Comment: take look on edited answer i add this  getApplicationContext() in the code to get the resource , i think the problem because the ListActivity can't read the resources  because its context feed me back

Comment: No, it crashes using the .getApplicationContext() method. Only the array worked so far.

Comment: the problem in the array you declared in resources files

Comment: I have added strings.xml in the original post. I can't seem to find anything wrong with it.